# RewriteRule with dynamic two parameters and one maybe missing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Rewriterule with two parameters and its working as it should.
But there is sometimes the possibility that the second parameter does not exist or is blank.

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ ./index.php?firma=$1 

RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.+)/?$ ./index.php?firma=$1&nimi=$2
```

the first $1 is numberic value
and second one is letters with.

Example of my problem.

I have a url:

> https://www.someserver.com/1255554-SOME-LETTERS-AS

this will work fine!

> https://www.someserver.com/1255554

This will work fine as well and opens the same page.
But as i have more than 250 000 pages some pages have the $2 part blank.
Then the generated URL is:

> https://www.someserver.com/1255554-

And now this aint showing, it will say 404
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make trailing hyphen optional in your first rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-?/?$ ./index.php?firma=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.+)/?$ ./index.php?firma=$1&nimi=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It is suggested to use `QSA` flag (Query String Append) when rewriting query string in your target URI.